# Locust : self.environment.runner.quit even the RPS still not 0

Tags: python, python-3.8, stress-testing, locust

I want to know when I use below function in python-locust code for stopping running when I get non 200 response code from testing API endpoint.

```
 if response.status_code != 200:
    self.environment.runner.quit()
```

When I met response code != 200, all users are stopping. The number of users graph is reduce to 0 but total requests per second are not(
[My problem graph picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFqIZ.png))

Why RPS not reduce to 0, please kindly tell me what exactly what it is ?

**PS.** *I use Python **3.8.2** and locust **1.4.1***

Thank you

Brs,

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example of the scenario that you are describing? complete code example of the locust test? Maybe point out if you are using workers to make locust distributed or what kind of setup are you using?

Comment: Thank you @AxelMendoza
Just running Locust and wait until response_code is not 200, this is the reproducible scenario for my case. The complete code is [here](https://gitlab.com/jung_pub/learning02/-/blob/master/load_test_03.py)
I set up load-test by "Number of total users to simulate" = 1 and "Spawn rate" = 1
Am I missing something in setup ?
Actually RPS should reduce to 0 when user stopped, am I correct ?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code using the host value from the original image. I get the error:

```
ConnectionError(ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer')))
```

So the response status code is 0 with an error and the test runner get stopped. I see everything ok in my side, but I run the latest code from:
https://github.com/locustio/locust

It seems that what you have experienced it's an issue already solved at:
https://github.com/locustio/locust/issues/1677

You could try to see if the issue remains after the new test with the latest Locust version 1.4.3 that it's already available on:
https://pypi.org/project/locust/

Comment: You received  response_code = 0 because the endpoint API I try to make load-test have an ACL that allowed only IP from my private network.

After I upgraded locust to `locust 1.4.3`, I try to test again but seem like the bug still occurred. This is the result picture [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zPKvIQ9f-gDNrkAH19iDNU0XEMkJovH3/view?usp=sharing),
But I'm very glad for your help, thank you so much @Axel

Comment: I already have a test environment to test your case. Could you remove the ACL for that endpoint so I could test it?. Let me know

Comment: I will try to asking my developer for allow ACL, thank you Axel Mendoza

Comment: @ Axel Mendoza My developer team don't allow me to off the ACL. But this is OK, let me try with others API. Thank you so much for your kindly answer.

Comment: Sure, no problem